# Ask for input, then redirect to website using the inputed data

Tags: javascript, html

[HTML]
So I want a simple website where the user is asked for input (will be order number) and when they click submit it sends them to a website using the inputted data in the URL.

I searched everywhere and cant find out how to do this.

I tried this with no luck.

```html
<h1> Whats your name ? </h1>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="tt" placeholder="Enter Name : ">
</form>
<button onclick="my()">Submit now</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Funnily enough, I put the title of this post in google search and the first result contains the answer for you: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1237315/Get-value-of-input-and-redirect-to-that-url-which

Comment: Trying to do with HTML though. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I wanna host this on a website

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript URL Redirection based on a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448147/javascript-url-redirection-based-on-a-text-box)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a GET request if you want to send data in the URL:

```html
<form action="yourURL" method="get">
  <label for="orderNumber">Order number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber">
  <button>Submit now</button>
</form>
```

For more information about HTML forms, please read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).